# Python - How to keep smallest number (converting from string to int) in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

If I have a list of elements such as:

```
items = ["058529-08704-200280", "058529-08704-230330", "058529-08704-140200", "058529-08704-290390", 
         "058529-08705-140200", "058529-08705-230330", "058529-08704-170240", "058529-08705-290390", 
         "058529-08705-170240"]
```

I want to keep the elements with the smallest number after the second " - ". However, they must be compared with the elements which have the same first two numbers in the string.

For e.g. the strings which start with `058529-08704`, the smallest number is `058529-08704-140200` and for `058529-08705`, the smallest number is `058529-08705-140200`

So the final list must end up with `["058529-08704-140200", "058529-08705-140200"]`.

What is the most pythonic way to achieve this instead of having to write multiple ifs or using string manipulation?

Comment: The most Pythonic way probably involves some ifs and some string manipulation.

Comment: Please provide your code, explain what you have tried, and if it work and you just need a review for a more pythonic code, go to the SE Code-Review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
items = ["058529-08704-200280", "058529-08704-230330", "058529-08704-140200", "058529-08704-290390",
         "058529-08705-140200", "058529-08705-230330", "058529-08704-170240", "058529-08705-290390",
         "058529-08705-170240"]
lst_3th_num = []
for item in items:
    lst_3th_num.append(int(item.split('-')[2]))

result = []
for item in items:
    if int(item.split('-')[2]) == min(int(s) for s in lst_3th_num):
        result.append(item)

print(result)
```